# Como baixar e importar livraria android v7-appcompat para o NetBeans?

Tags: android, netbeans, app-compat-v7

Gostaria de saber como faço para importar a um projeto, usando o NetBeans, a livraria  android v7-appcompat. Estou usando um código para estudos e o Net Beans não está reconhecendo algumas linhas de códigos.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AppCompatCallback { 
                                        /// Não Reconhece AppCompatCallback
private AppCompatDelegate delegate;
         /// Não Reconhece AppCompatDelegate
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quanto ao download, no site do Android para desenvolvedores há [um guia](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/support-library/setup.html) explicando detalhadamente como baixar.

Após o download, para fazer uso dela, expanda a árvore do projeto no Netbeans e:

- Clique com o botão direito do mouse no diretório "Bibliotecas";
- Escolha "Adicionar JAR/Pasta";
- Procure pelo diretório em que se encontra o arquivo .jar e o selecione.

Feito isso já será possível usar as classes do .jar no seu projeto.

<kbd>[image: importar]</kbd>